# jersey RESTful ressource, 500 error

Tags: hibernate, rest, jaxb, jersey, jersey-client

I'm new to RESTful web services, i'm working on a web service that :

1. consumes a stream of XML ( through jersey Client )
2. then marshal the XML into Java Object
3. and finally persist this java object using hibernate.

the unmarshalling and everything is working good, but whenever i try to access the service layer to use the "persist" method before returning a response, I get a response with **500 error**.

Even if I put the whole hibernate code in the web service body without accessing the service layer, i get a response with **500 error**.  I have no idea how to handle this, your help is really needed.

project classes:

JAXB

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class Student {

@XmlElement 
private int id;
@XmlElement
private String firstName;
@XmlElement
private String lastName;
@XmlElement
private int age;

public Student() { }

// getters and setters

}
```

Model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class StudentModel {
@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name="ID")
private int id;

@Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="LASTNAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="AGE")
private int age;

public StudentModel() { }

// getters and setters

}
```

StudentRest Class

```
@Path("/xmlServices")
public class StudentRest{   

@POST
@Path("/send")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)

public Response consumeXML( Student student ) {
   // JAXB TO MODEL
  StudentModel model=new StudentModel();
  model.setFirstName(student.getFirstName());
  model.setLastName(student.getLastName());
  model.setAge(student.getAge());

       Session session = null;
       Transaction tx = null;
       session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       tx = session.beginTransaction();

       session.save(model);

       tx.commit();
       session.close();



     String output = student.toString();

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
}
```

jerseyClient Class

```
 public class JerseyClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Student st = new Student("Adriana", "Barrer", 12, 9);

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("http://localhost:8080/JerseyXMLExample/rest/xmlServices/send");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, st);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Server response : \n");
        System.out.println(output);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

}
```

HelpMeExceptionMapper class

```
 @Provider
 public class HelpMeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>{

 public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return Response
                .status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .entity(e.getCause())
                .build();
}


}
```

Stack trace :

```
toResponse started 
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
at    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)
atcom.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
toResponse Finished
```

Comment: If there is no exception mapper to handle exceptions, it will often just bubble up to the container level with a generic internal server error response. I would suggest writing an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` for debugging purposes. And just print the stacktrace. It is likely that the information required to debug will be shown in the trace. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e435) if you are unsure how to implement the mapper.

Comment: @peeskillet thank u for the quick response. i've understood your idea and i've created the Exception class that is implementing ExceptionMapper<Exception> with overiding the toResponse in order to print the stack trace, but what is the next step ?

Comment: i mean how should i use this class in my code to print the stacktrace ?

Comment: You see the `@Provider` annotation? If your configuration is to scan your resources (to register them), the mapper class should also automatically be registered through the scanning, because of that annotation. Add a print statement in the constructor of the mapper to see if it is being registered. Oh and you print the stacktrace inside the `toResponse` method of the mapper. If an exception occurs ,it should go through this method\

Comment: @peeskillet i see brother, i tried but in vain, look at the MapperClass i've added its code in the publication, please write for me the next step or the code that will make this class do the job,  my skills are very limited

Comment: How is your `StudentRest` being registered with the application? Is it scanned for (base on your configuration)? Or do you explicitly register it? It the former, your mapper will be registered the same way. If the latter, then register the mapper the same way. Add a print statement inside the constructor of the mapper to make sure that is it being created. If all it good, when the exception occurs on the server side, the framework will pass the exception through to the `toResponse` method. We don't need to do anything else. So 1. Make sure the print statement in the constructor is occurring...

Comment: ... 2. Send the request and hopefully the exception stack trace will print

Comment: @peeskillet thank you that was helpful but i had to add also Singleton annotation after the Provider annotation, now i can see the error it's a javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException do u have any idea how to handle it  ?

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace. (edit your question)

Comment: @peeskillet it's done, check it